# GTK4 ApplicationWindow that is also a ScrolledWindow?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

Here is a minimal GTK 4 app written using the Python bindings, based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/Taiko2k/GTK4PythonTutorial). It displays a window with a very long block of text:

```py
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Adw


class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        long_label = Gtk.Label.new("Here is a very long chunk of text.\n" * 100)
        self.set_child(long_label)

class MyApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.win = MainWindow(application=app)
        self.win.present()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(application_id="com.example.GtkApplication")
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

The tutorial uses the class `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` for the MainWindow, which lets you set the `application_id` in the main function and other convenient features.

However, the default `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` does *not* include a scrollbar. Rather than build one manually, it seems the best way to do this is to make my main window an instance of `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`, documented [here](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.ScrolledWindow.html), which lets you specify the scroll behavior etc. at a high level.

Unfortunately, dropping `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` in place of `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` causes an error:

```
TypeError: gobject `__main__+MainWindow' doesn't support property `application'
```

- **Is there a way to create a `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` that is also a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`?**
- **If not, what is the best way to get a scrollbar in my main window?**'

(I have added the `pygobject` tag because it is the language of my MWE, but I think that my question is agnostic with respect to the binding language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` isn't really a "window" per se as most people know it (it used to map to the very specific concept of a X11 Window). It's a widget that allows you to scroll through its child widget.

In other words, if you want an application window where you can scroll through the content, you would wrap your `Gtk.Label` with a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` and you would then set that as the `Gtk.ApplicationWindow`'s child.

In other words, your MainWindow would become:

```py
class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        long_label = Gtk.Label(label=("Here is a very long chunk of text.\n" * 100))

        # Wrap a scrolled window around it
        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled.set_child(long_label)

        # Set it as the main child of the window
        self.set_child(scrolled)
```